# What does "dives fluminarum" mean?

Tags: meaning

Can anybody explain the two last words in the following sentence?

> Veni, venite, spiritus sylvani, dives fluminarum.

The beginning seems to be "Come, come, the spirit of woods" or something of the kind. The context is the following: Two little boys are playing and one of them,  who is learning Latin, wants to show how he will summon magical spirits of nature. So perhaps there can be mistakes in the sentence.

Comment: Hah, "Veni, venite" is a clever way of saying "come one, come all".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Venī, venīte* means "come" in both singular and plural. Perhaps "come one, come all" would be a good translation? Personally I would just have used *venīte* twice.

*Spīritŭs* means "spirit", while *spīritūs* means "spirits"; without the length marking on the *u* it could mean either. But the adjective *sylvānī* "of the forest" makes it clear that it's plural "spirits".

I'm guessing that *dīvēs* is a mistake. Literally it means something like "wealthy people"; a connection to *dīvus* "divine" exists, but is extremely old and doesn't really affect the meaning any more. *Flūminārum* is definitely a mistake: it means "of the rivers", but using the first declension ending on a third declension noun. It's like saying "childs" instead of "children" in English: it's easy to understand the meaning, but native speakers would consider it wrong.

As for the intended meaning, ignoring the mistakes, I'd say:

> Come one, come all, spirits of the forest, divinities of the rivers.

(All the mistakes, by the way, are perfectly reasonable from a child who's just learning the language.)

EDIT: As Hugh pointed out in the comments, while *sylvānus* literally means "of the forest", it's most often used as the title of a particular deity. The more usual word for "of the forest" is *sylvaticus*.

Comment: *Sylvanus, Silvanus* is usually the Forest God himself; and *silvaticus* the woodland adjective.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice answer, so deep,  for  explanations.

Comment: @Hugh Good call! Added

Answer (score 5):

This so neatly recreates all the oddities of medieval popular and superstitious *hocus pocus* Latin. All the words are real Latin except *fluminarum,* which is a neuter-plural ***'-a'*** mistaken for a First declension singular.

All the other words would have been familiar to a bright child:
*[Veni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Come,_O_Come,_Emmanuel) & [Venite](https://hymnary.org/tune/venite_adoremus)* from Christmas carols.

*Dives* from the legend of [Dives and Lazarus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dives_and_Lazarus_(ballad)) based on a parable (Luke 16:19–31); the Rich Man and the Beggar covered in sores; who became patron of leper hospitals as S. Lazare.

*Silvanus* or *Sylvanus* is the God of woods and forests; introduced by Kipling or Hawthorne or C.S.Lewis to children's literature.

Comment: What is "medieval *hocus pocus* Latin"?

Comment: brianpck  *hocus-pocus* "Early 17th century: from hax pax max Deus adimax, a pseudo-Latin phrase **used as a magic formula by conjurors**." Oxford Dictionary on-line